# Docker pull limit on Private registry

Tags: docker, openshift, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I actually have deployed an openshift cluster in conjunction with the internal private openshift registry. I am using OKD3. My team's developers use gitlab Community edition and gitlab-ci as part of our ci and deploy our web app in openshift using source to image strategy.

We actually faced the famous pull limit from dockerhub and came up with the idea of using the images from our own internal openshift registry to do our builds. Unfortunately we ended with a pipeline failed because of pull limit even though the registry used was our own internal openshift registry.

Is there any chance that the pull limit apply to all kind of docker registry private and public ? ( not only the docker hub)
Or perhaps is this limit comming from Gitlab-ci itself ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any chance that the pull limit apply to all kind of docker registry private and public ? ( not only the docker hub) Or perhaps is this limit comming from Gitlab-ci itself ?

No, it is not possible. If you hit the pull limit, it's because you're pulling from Hub (or some other registry that implements limits, none of which I'm aware of). What you're pulling can't be identified from the question, but it may be your Gitlab runner image, it may be some base image that is still pointing to Hub.